# itext xmlworker with javafx htmleditor

Tags: java, javafx-2, pdf-generation, itext, xmlworker

I created a simple JavaFX (2.2) FXML project. I am trying to convert a html string to different Elements and add them to a Paragraph in my PDF document generated by iText. As HTMLWorker is deprecated, I use XMLWorker. It does seem to work with a own written simple html string, e.g.:

```
StringReader in = new StringReader("<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>");
```

However, when I try to use the html string generated by the JavaFX HTMLEditor control, I receive following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.pdfelement.NoNewLineParagraph.setMultipliedLeading(F)V
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.currentContentToParagraph(AbstractTagProcessor.java:268)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Span.end(Span.java:77)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.endElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:192)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.close(HtmlPipeline.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:142)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:396)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:71)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:236)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:214)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:149)
at hmtltopdf.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:64)
... 54 more
```

My guess is that there are a bunch of tags in the html string that aren't recognized by XMLWorker. The HTML editor creates this html string:

```
<html><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p style="text-align: left;"><font face="'Segoe UI'">test</font></p></body></html>
```

If that is the case, is there a way to 'clean' the html string? Or do I have to use another HTML editor of some sort?

Code of my sample project:

```
//using iText 5.3.1 and XMLWorker 5.5.0

@FXML
private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    final Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/test/loremipsum.pdf"));

    document.open();

    //StringReader in = new StringReader("<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>"); //this works
    StringReader in = new StringReader(htmlEditor.getHtmlText()); //this does not work

    try {
        final Paragraph test = new Paragraph();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new ElementHandler() {
            @Override
            public void add(final Writable w) {
                if (w instanceof WritableElement) {
                    List<Element> elements = ((WritableElement) w).elements();
                    for (Element e : elements) {
                        test.add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, in);

        document.add(test);
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    document.close();
}
```

Edit:

It seems the problems start when using `<b>`, `<i>`, ... or other tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah it seems that it has to do something with using an older iText version. I've updated to iText 5.5.0 and it seems to work now. I still had to remove any `<br>` and `<hr>` tags thou.

```
//using iText 5.5.0 and XMLWorker 5.5.0

@FXML
private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    final Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/test/loremipsum.pdf"));

    document.open();

    String htmlString = htmlEditor.getHtmlText();

    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<br>", "");
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<br/>", "");
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<br />", "");

    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<hr>", "<p></p>");
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<hr/>", "<p></p>");
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("<hr />", "<p></p>");

    StringReader in = new StringReader(htmlString);

    try {
        final Paragraph test = new Paragraph();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new ElementHandler() {
            @Override
            public void add(final Writable w) {
                if (w instanceof WritableElement) {
                    List<Element> elements = ((WritableElement) w).elements();
                    for (Element e : elements) {
                        test.add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, in);

        document.add(test);
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems the version of iText and the version of XMLWorker must always be equal.